# Special name for this Ito's process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-filtering

I came across with this formula coming from the optimal filtering of stochastic process.

$$dX_{t} = X_{t} (1-X_{t})  dt + X_{t} (1-X_{t}) \sigma dZ_{t}$$

where $\sigma$ denotes the variance of Brownian motion $Z_{t}$. Would there be a special name on this class of process?

Thank you very much.